# Javascript removeEventListener("beforeunload") not working

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have a Web Worker sending messages to the main page.

I add an listener for the *message* event of the Web Worker:

- when the content of the message is *0*, I add a listener to the window object for the *beforeunload* event.
- when the content of the message is *1*, I remove the previous listener for the *beforeunload* event.

Here is the main page: (main.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
new Worker("worker.js").addEventListener("message",function(e){
    function unloadPage(e){
        console.info("event triggered",e);
    }

    if(e.data==0){
        console.log("event added");
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload",unloadPage,false);
    }
    else{
        console.log("event removed");
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",unloadPage,false);
    }
},false);
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

And here is the Web Worker: (worker.js)

```
postMessage(0);
postMessage(1);
```

Content of the console:

```
"event added"
"event removed"
```

Since I use the same event (*beforeunload*), the same function (*unloadPage*) and the same third parameter (*false*) when adding or removing, i expect the event to be correctly removed.

**But when I refresh the page, the *unloadPage*() function is called.**

If I declare *unloadPage* in the global scope, the event is correctly removed. But I don't want to do that.

I feel like *unloadPage* in *addEventListener* is not the same as *unloadPage* in *removeEventListener*, but i don't understand why since it is the same function.

I tested on Firefox 45.0 and 47.0.

Comment: you are right. `unloadPage` is always a new function each time a message arrives.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `unloadPage` was always the same function since it is not an anonymous function. I guess i must declare `unloadPage` outside of the message listener's function.